# ini file: differentiate between (int)1 and boolean

Tags: php, ini

I am currently using `ini` format for configuration files. I really like this format for no technical reason, actually. I'm having quite a bit of trouble with differentiating between `1` and `(bool)true`. Sadly, no matter what I put as a value - `true`, `yes`, `on` - when I parse the file into PHP they all get converted to `(string) "1"`. This is a problem for me because I'm building a GUI for editing config. files and in order to make it all nice and pretty I want to have `boolean` values be `boolean` values and `int` values be `int` values.

Essentially what I'm asking is - how can I turn this `ini` file

```
bool = true
int = 1
```

Into this PHP object ( array actually )

```
Array (
    ['bool'] => (bool) true
    ['int'] => (int) 1
)
```

Instead of what I'm getting

```
Array (
    ['bool'] => (string) "1"
    ['int'] => (string) "1"
)
```

I'm trying to avoid writing my own parser, because one does not simply write a better parser than the guys from PHP.net

Comment: This is a known issue: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38409 and fixes are slated for 5.6.1 onwards.

Comment: @kums I just downloaded version `5.6.1` and it is the same O.o

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for [`parse_ini_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php), as of 5.6.1 passing `INI_SCANNER_TYPED` will preserve the setting type (int, bool, etc.) where possible.

Example: https://3v4l.org/EkLhs#v561